# Is there a way to save an adjusted image from a named Window in opencv in Python?

Tags: python-3.x, opencv

Just a general question - I made a contrast slider, so I could open images and adjust their brightness and/or contrast to what best fits my needs. However, how can I save those settings resp. overwrite the image with those settings once I close the window?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: You somewhere compute/generate the image, just remember it there. Afaik you cabt fetch window closing events in opencv, but maybe with additional python modules.

Answer (score 0):

Unless I am misunderstanding your question, I think you just need to make sure you are saving the adjusted image to a different file path. The code below might help you. You can insert the datetime into the file name if you want a new image to be saved each time.

```
import cv2
from datetime import datetime

def some_adjustment(img):
    """
    your adjustment
    """
    return img

path = "img.jpg"
img = cv2.imread(path)

adjusted_img = some_adjustment(img)

cv2.imshow('adjusted_img', adjusted_img)

cv2.waitKey(0)
now = datetime.now()
dt_string = now.strftime("%m.%d.%Y.%H.%M.%S")
cv2.imwrite(f"adjusted_{dt_string}.png", adjusted_img)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```